# Double integral $x^2(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 x^2(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2} \ dx \ dy$ ? I tried substituting $x^2+y^2=tan^2(u)$ but it becomes more complicated. Using [Wolfram Alpha Widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+%5B%2F%2Fmath:x2(x2%2By2%2B1)%5E(3%2F2)%2F%2F%5D+%5B%2F%2Fmath:dx+dy%2F%2F%5D+for+x+from+%5B%2F%2Fmath:-1%2F%2F%5D+to+%5B%2F%2Fmath:1%2F%2F%5D+for+y+from+%5B%2F%2Fmath:-1%2F%2F%5D+to+%5B%2F%2Fmath:1%2F%2F%5D) the answer is $3.64092$. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: In your link, integrand was just $1-x^2-y^2,$ not as in the integral of the question.

Comment: @coffeemath It is just a link to the widget.

Comment: TED-- Did it give an "exact" value (closed form) or only an approximation $3.64092$? I ask since it may be there is no closed form-- WA usually finds one if it exists, I'm not familiar with Widget, which may only be a small subset of WA.

Comment: Above I should only have said "often finds", not "usually".

Comment: @coffeemath It doesn't give closed form. I used the widget just to sort of know what value to expect from the integral.

Comment: The value does have an elementary closed form, but it is tedious.  I am in the process of providing a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symmetry of the integrand implies $$I = \int_{y=-1}^1 \int_{x=-1}^1 x^2 (x^2 + y^2 + 1)^{3/2} \, dx \, dy = \int_{x=-1}^1 \int_{y=-1}^1 y^2 (x^2 + y^2 + 1)^{3/2} \, dy \, dx.$$  Thus $$2I = \int_{y=-1}^1 \int_{x=-1}^1 (x^2 + y^2)(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^{3/2} \, dx \, dy.$$  Now perform the coordinate transformation $$(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$$ to obtain $$2I = 8 \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/4} \int_{r = 0}^{\sec \theta} r^2 (r^2 + 1)^{3/2} r \, dr \, d\theta.$$  Since
$$\begin{align*} \int r^3 (r^2 + 1)^{3/2} \, dr
&= \frac{1}{2} \int r^2 (r^2 + 1)^{3/2} 2r \, dr \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int (u-1)u^{3/2} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{2}{7} u^{7/2} - \frac{2}{5} u^{5/2} \right) + C \\
&= \frac{(r^2+1)^{7/2}}{7} - \frac{(r^2+1)^{5/2}}{5} + C,
\end{align*}$$
we obtain 
$$
I = 4 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}  \frac{(\sec^2 \theta + 1)^{7/2} - 1}{7} - \frac{(\sec^2 \theta + 1)^{5/2} - 1}{5} \, d\theta.$$
At this point, I don't have a simple way to evaluate this integral; however, the value provided is $$I = \frac{2}{105}\left(96 \sqrt{3} + \pi + 33 \coth^{-1} \sqrt{3} \right) \approx 3.640919532942123602084014417112851989279\ldots.$$

Comment: It is quite tedious (not simple, as you wrote) but we can get the antiderivatives and then the integrals appearing befor the result. This is a nice solution ! $\to +1$. Cheers.